# Prolog SWI List creation

Tags: list, prolog

Knowledge Representation:

```
student('John','f214','A').
student('John','f222','B').
student('John','f213','C').
student('John','f343','D').

subject(f214,3).
subject(f222,3).
subject(f213,3).
subject(f343,3).
```

From the given knowledge representation in Prolog SWI How can I create list of courses [f214,f222,f213,f343] and list of corresponding grades ['A','B','C','D']

Comment: I do not get how a course will be assigned a single grade, is it some kind of aggregation like the average grade students who attended that course got?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findall/3`:

```
?- findall(Course, subject(Course, _), Courses).
Courses = [f214, f222, f213, f343].

?- findall(Grade, student(_,Grade,_), Grades).
Grades = [f214, f222, f213, f343].

?- findall(course_grade(Course, Grade), (subject(Course,_), student(_,Course,Grade)), CoursesGrades).
CoursesGrades = [course_grade(f214, 'A'), course_grade(f222, 'B'), course_grade(f213, 'C'), course_grade(f343, 'D')].
```